# Karma-jasmine running is hang when test case have 23?

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I've got a weird problem: If I run Karma with exactly 23 test cases, then the test is hanging. But if I run Karma with any other number of test cases (24,25,26), it works quickly. What issue could cause that?

karmar.conf.js

```
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js')
// karma.conf.js
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    // this is the entry file for all our tests.
    files: ['index.js'],
    // we will pass the entry file to webpack for bundling.
    preprocessors: {
      'index.js': ['webpack']
    },
    // use the webpack config
    webpack: webpackConfig,
    // avoid walls of useless text
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true
    },
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 100000,
    reporters: ["spec"],
    singleRun: true
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think my test case code have wrong pattern so it took so long to test ! Here is a few things I notice that my test case have become more faster

1. I need to provide full mock data (data, props ) and other component that show warning on test case
2. I mistakenly took many Dom elements to test
3. I need to use some param to use on test callback. If it’s not, it will finish synchronously